# Prevent Wordpress from word wrapping comma-separated words

Tags: css, wordpress

In wordpress, when I enter a bunch of comma-separated words, double words (eg. My Portfolio)
gets wrapped.

eg.

```
career, id, my portfolio, contacts
```

would render in the browser as this:

```
career, id, my 
portfolio, contacts
```

How do i prevent this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&nbsp;` between words you don't want to separate.